# SharePoint Online - managed properties doesn´t appear in the display template

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

The issue basically is that i need to create a custom column in a list to store  some data and after that i need to retrieve that information in a content search web part, so what i've done is to try to crawl this column and create a managed property that allows me get this information later.

[image: crawl and managed property]

but when i try to get the info in the content search web part, seems like it doesn´t find it.

[image: query]

i'm really new working with SharePoint if someone can bring me some help or tell me what is happening, i'll appreciate it so much

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why `SalarioOWS` is not showing because it is probably not refinable and that why You have to map SalarioOWS to one of the refinable properties like `RefinableStringxx` or `RefinableIntxx` (depends on the data type of Salario)

you can follow this guide to map it a refinable property:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2013/11/10/how-to-add-refiners-to-your-search-results-page-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: okay thanks man, i'll try that, but before it worked without do that, do you know why?

Comment: I would check the properties of SalarioOWS and see if something has changed (is it refinable, sortable, etc.) Did you change its data type or something?

Comment: yeah i didn't change anything but it was not working, but now it does, i did what you said and now it's perfect thank you so man man!. :)

Comment: can you please mark it as an answer then :)...
Good Luck!